# Rackspace CloudFile API - get object information

Tags: openstack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, openstack-swift, rackspace-cloudfiles

So, here's what I'm doing with the API:

1. Auth (to get token and publicUrl for the particular region I need from the "object-store")
2. Use the publicUrl from the endpoint like so to get a list of files:
   GET [publicUrl]/[container]
   This returns an array where each item (object) looks like the following:

   (
       [hash] => 7213ee9a7d9dc119d2921a40e899ec5e
       [last_modified] => 2015-12-29T02:46:08.400490
       [bytes] => 1
       [name] => Some type of file name.jpg
       [content_type] => application/postscript
   )

Now, how do I build the url to do a GET on the item (object)?  I've tried the following:

[publicUrl]/[container]/[hash]
[publicUrl]/[container]/urlencoded([name])

among other things that don't make sense, but I tried anyway.

Any thoughts/help would be appreciated!

Comment: What language are you using? Are you using an SDK or using the API directly?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a [Rackspace SDK](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/#sdks), you can skip building the URLs yourself.

Here is the documentation for [retrieving a Cloud Files object using a public URL](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/v1/developer-guide/#list-metadata-for-cdn-enabled-container). The object URL is the combination of the public URL of the container (found in the X-Cdn-Uri response header) with the object name appended.

For example, for a container named 'foo', send an authenticated HEAD request to the API:

```
HEAD {cloudFilesEndpoint}/foo
```

In the response, the container's public URL is in the 'X-Cdn-Uri' header:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
X-Cdn-Ssl-Uri: https://83c49b9a2f7ad18250b3-346eb45fd42c58ca13011d659bfc1ac1.ssl.cf0.rackcdn.com
X-Ttl: 259200
X-Cdn-Uri: http://081e40d3ee1cec5f77bf-346eb45fd42c58ca13011d659bfc1ac1.r49.cf0.rackcdn.com
X-Cdn-Enabled: True
X-Log-Retention: False
X-Cdn-Streaming-Uri: http://084cc2790632ccee0a12-346eb45fd42c58ca13011d659bfc1ac1.r49.stream.cf0.rackcdn.com
X-Trans-Id: tx82a6752e00424edb9c46fa2573132e2c
Content-Length: 0
```

Now, for an object named 'styles/site.css', append that name to the public URL, resulting in the following URL:

```
http://081e40d3ee1cec5f77bf-346eb45fd42c58ca13011d659bfc1ac1.r49.cf0.rackcdn.com/styles/site.css
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Is this the same for containers that are not CDN enabled?

Comment: If you want the object to be publicly accessible, then the container must be CDN enabled. [Objects in private containers can only be accessed with an authenticated GET request](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/v1/developer-guide/#retrieving-an-object).

Comment: So, I *am* authenticating using the apikey, and sending the token in the subsequent requests..

Comment: Yes, if you don't make the container public by enabling CDN, then you must authenticate and use a token to retrieve objects.

Did my answer work for you or are you still having trouble?

Comment: It turned out that the url wasn't being returned in a HEAD request for me.  I ended up figuring out that I was doing it right to begin with, but I wasn't url-encoding the file name properly (it was encoding spaces as "+" symbols instead of "%20").  I appreciated your response, as it helped my keep troubleshooting and get to the answer!